# Rewrite rule that wp-login.php?action=register is left alone

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

Unfortunately buddypress breaks a facebook connect script because of the rewrite rules. It changes `/wp-login.php?action=register` into `/register/`

I tried to find where the custom rewrite rule is located but wasn't successful. Is there any way to just add something to .htaccess that wp leaves /wp-login.php?action=register alone?

I tried some things like

```
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ - [PT,L]
```

but it didn't work.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: What version of BuddyPress are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're working with one of the latest versions, but I used the latest 1.5.1. Without knowing how your specific Facebook Connect plugin works and why it breaks here's what I've come up with.

### Short answer

```
// bp-members/bp-members-signup.php ~ line 611
if ( defined( 'BP_SKIP_REGISTRATION_REDIRECT' ) and BP_SKIP_REGISTRATION_REDIRECT )
    wp_redirect( '/?pagename=register' );
```

And a filter:

```
function wpse31346_filter_bp_uri( $path ) {
    if ($path == '?pagename=register')
        return '/register';
    return $path;
}
add_filter( 'bp_uri', 'wpse31346_filter_bp_uri' );
```

### Long answer

`bp_core_wpsignup_redirect()` is the function that contains the redirect you're talking about.
http://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/1.5.1/bp-members/bp-members-signup.php#L604

And as you can sadly see, there is no hook that allows you to alter the behavior. So you'll most likely have to hack the BuddyPress core yourself.

By adding something like:

```
// Not at the WP core signup page and action is not register
if ( false === strpos( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'wp-signup.php' ) && ( 'register' != $action ) )
    return;

if ( defined( 'BP_SKIP_REGISTRATION_REDIRECT' ) and BP_SKIP_REGISTRATION_REDIRECT ) return;

// Redirect to sign-up page
if ( locate_template( array( 'registration/register.php' ), false ) || locate_template( array( 'register.php' ), false ) )
    bp_core_redirect( bp_get_signup_page() );
```

Then simply add `define( 'BP_SKIP_REGISTRATION_REDIRECT', true )` to your `wp-config.php` file an it should skip the redirect. **However**, accessing the link now will show the default WordPress registration page, ouch. This may disrupt user-experience.

The BuddyPress "rewriting" system is quite intricate (it's called a "URI catcher"), in this case it breaks the request down and searches for an exact match in page slugs to provide the final URL, and the page slug in this case is `register`.

So let's think a bit, what other way is there to access the `register` page in our case without resorting to the `/register` request? You'd be tempted to redirect to `index.php?pagename=register`, however that doesn't work, that page is empty and isn't being caught by the BuddyPress URI catcher, another ouch.

When `register` is identified in the `/register` URL it sets the `$bp->current_component` to `register`. However we can neither set the `current_component` to `register` nor directly call `bp_load_template('registration/register')` as the `$bp` global is has not been initialized at the point of redirection.

We can raise a flag perhaps? By implementing this hack:

```
if ( defined( 'BP_SKIP_REGISTRATION_REDIRECT' ) and BP_SKIP_REGISTRATION_REDIRECT ) {
    define( 'BP_SHOW_REGISTRATION_PAGE', true );
    return;
}
```

There appears to be no clean way of hooking into anything into this process, `bp_load_template()`, which gives us a chance to filter the template, will not be executed without the URI catcher's match, it simply returns with the comment `// This is not a BuddyPress page, so just return.` http://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/1.5.1/bp-core/bp-core-catchuri.php#L209

There is a filter high above in the function http://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/1.5.1/bp-core/bp-core-catchuri.php#L54 called `bp_uri`, which we can potentially hook into to alter what BuddyPress perceives, like so:

```
function wpse31346_filter_bp_uri( $path ) {
    if ($path == '/wp-login.php?action=register')
        return '/register';
    return $path;
}
add_filter( 'bp_uri', 'wpse31346_filter_bp_uri' );
```

**Yet**, WordPress will still load its `wp-login.php` even in the event that we managed to match and hack BuddyPress into setting its `current_component` to `register`; `bp_load_tempalate()` is not being reached.

I remind you of the problem at hand - we can't get the BuddyPress registration page to display after successfully stopping the redirect, just in case your forgot :)

The `bp_screens` action is fired off with the `wp` action, which is not fired off when `wp-login.php` is requested, so it's off the hook. We can maybe redirect to `?pagename=register`, `bp_screens` is fired off, so the `bp_uri` filter alterations will successfully avalanche over to `bp_load_template()`.

Thus, after quite a long conversation with myself, I'm offering the following solution involving a core hack:

```
// bp-members/bp-members-signup.php ~ line 611
if ( defined( 'BP_SKIP_REGISTRATION_REDIRECT' ) and BP_SKIP_REGISTRATION_REDIRECT )
    wp_redirect( '/?pagename=register' );
```

And a filter:

```
function wpse31346_filter_bp_uri( $path ) {
    if ($path == '?pagename=register')
        return '/register';
    return $path;
}
add_filter( 'bp_uri', 'wpse31346_filter_bp_uri' );
```

### Conclusion

Hopefully my answer has provided enough insight into how BuddyPress works and how inflexible this URI catching system appears to be. This is my first time looking into BuddyPress, so I must have probably missed something important while browsing the source code and documentation, so hopefully someone will provide some additional tips and solutions to improve the answer.

If you can provide more information on why it breaks and what is required by the Facebook Connect plugin I can further improve my answer. Maybe it doesn't like the redirect at all? Or wants the standard WordPress login page? Can't know without more info.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I end up at url.com/?pagename=register which is just the empty page template though. Isn't there a way to simply whitelist the wp-login.php? :/

Comment: If you're ending up at the empty page called "Register" then your filter does not appear to be working. You should be careful where add the filter, you're doing it too late most probably, long after it's been fired off. Try to `die('Filtering...)` inside the function to see if it's being called at least.

Comment: Do I have to change anything in your code? It works, well it does change something as I said I get to another url now but it's simply not the one I need. I would also send you money via Paypal if you could fix this. DRIVING ME NUTS!

Comment: This is a Pay it Forward http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward community, let me know where you want `wp-login.php?action=register` to go.